# Conditionally change the values in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I added a new variable (all zeros) to my old data frame. Now in this new data frame, I have to change the value from 0 to 1 for observations who meet the condition. The condition is on the other variable.

For example, I have variables `x`,`y`,`z` in this new data frame. `z` is the new variable I just added, they are all zero. If `y=some number a`, I want `z=1`.

I try to use a simple for loop to accomplish this, but I have no idea where I did wrong.

```
for (i==999 in data$y) {
    {data$z==1} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to set `data$z` to be 1 when `data$y` is 999, and set it to be 0 otherwise. This can be accomplished with:

```
data$z = as.numeric(data$y == 999)
```

Answer (score 2):

It would have helped if you gave us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  I'll create one instead:

```
df = data.frame(x = sample.int(5, 5),
                y = sample.int(5, 5),
                z = rep(0, 5))

df
  x y z
1 3 3 0
2 4 5 0 
3 2 1 0
4 5 4 0
5 1 2 0
```

Your problem states that you are trying to change values of `df$z` when some condition in `y` is met.  In R, the general way to do this is to use subscripts.  I highly recommend John Cook's blog post [5 Kinds of Subscripts in R](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/23/five-kinds-of-r-language-subscripts/) to help understand this; it's one of those things in R that just works differently than most other languages, but when you get the hang of it it becomes very handy.

So in this case:

```
# where is y==1?
df$y == 1
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

We can feed this resulting logical vector into the row index of an expression like `df[row, column]`

```
df[df$y == 1, ]
  x y z
3 2 1 0
```

And if we want to set the value of the "z" column in that row to be something, just type

```
df[df$y == 1, "z"] = 999
df
  x y   z
1 3 3   0
2 4 5   0
3 2 1 999
4 5 4   0
5 1 2   0
```